# Is it possible to get Team ID of my iOS app programmatically?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to fetch team id associated with the iOS app programmatically?

Comment: it is part of the `.ipa` after you have singed it off, you could extract it from the `embedded.mobileprovision` file, I guess, but it is not clear _from where_ you'd like to access to such information programmatically.